# $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2+y^2 > c\}$ is neither open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology, vector-analysis

Why
$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2+y^2 > c\} \space (c > 0) $$is neither open nor closed?

Answer (score 4):

That's wrong. It's an open set, as it is the preimage of $(c, \infty) \subseteq \mathbf R$ under the continuous map $f\colon (x,y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$. It's not closed, as $x_n := (\sqrt c + \frac 1n, 0)$ belongs to the set for every $n \in \mathbf N$, but the limit of the $x_n$, namely $(\sqrt c,0)$, does not.

Comment: Since $(0,0)$ doesn't belong to the set, it's not closed or $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be disconnected. `;-)`